# One word to refer to live streams and videos?

Tags: single-word-requests

How would you refer to internet live streams and videos in one word?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could be called a "feed".

Comment: In the old days, we called this *television* and *radio*. But in the old days, we also had to distinguish between previously recorded and live broadcasts. The same will continue to be true for Internet broadcasts.

Comment: "content" may encompass more than you intend; "streamed content" would hit the mark.

Comment: The word you're looking for is "video". Video includes live video, streaming video, downloaded video, and computer generated video.

Answer (score -1):

Not precisely with one word, but you can with two: Transport Protocols.

Depending upon the context you could use 'protocol' to define both a live stream and a video stream.

'Feed', as mentioned above, is a good answer; regularly used to describe both.

As mentioned in the comments, protocol is most probably not the word required. Perhaps quite simply "media" or "medium" would fit your requirements.

Comment: Not all live video streams are UDP, and not all UDP streams are video. I don't think any non-live videos are UDP.

Comment: I guess that is why the buffer stops the video on youtube ... Perhaps "Transport Protocols" would be a better way of putting it.

Comment: YouTube uses TCP, not UDP. Transport protocols are used for many things beyond video--including web pages. This page was delivered to you over TCP. 'Protocol' has a definition very different than this and is inappropriate.

Comment: Yes they are very "general terms" of course tcp and udp are the main transport protocols for the web generally; just had the thought that 'media' fits the bill quite well.

Answer (score -1):

[It it unclear from question if the *videos*, being referred to, are streamed or downloaded or both, so will try to cover several cases here ...]

**Multimedia** from wikipedia is

> text, audio, images, animation, video and interactive content.
>   text, audio, images, animation, video andinteractive content.

**Streaming media** is a type of multimedia. It is **not** downloaded in advance. According to [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_media) it is

> multimedia that is constantly received by and presented to an end-user while being delivered by a provider.

And as described at wikipedia, **live streaming** is a special case of this, i.e.

> content delivered live over the Internet.

Perhaps *non-live streaming* could serve as an antoymn.